# Can not render view in TinyWeb framework

Tags: c#, .net, spark-view-engine, tinyweb

I am trying to render a simple view with the TinyWeb framework and Spark view engine.

Enviroment is Visual Studio 2011 developer preview & .net 4.5

Rendering a template with no model binding works fine.
However when I bind a model then it no longer works.

I get this error:
The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context.

Handler:

```
public class IndexHandler
{
    Route route = new Route("/");

    public IResult Get()
    {
        var model = new { message = "Hello World" };
        return View.Spark(model, "Views/base.spark");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>${Model.message}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using an anonymous object which as far as I am aware will not work, you can either use a full model class or a dynamic object.

```
var model = new MyModel { message = "Hello World" };
```

And then have `<viewdata model="MyModel">` in the view or,

```
dynamic model = new { message = "Hello World" };
```

And then specify `<viewdata model="dynamic">` in the view.

Comment: Setting a full model class worked. Could not get the dynamic model to work.

Answer (score 4):

Do  you not have to let spark now what model is?

e.g.

```
<viewdata currentProduct="Product"/>
```

see here: http://invalidcast.com/2011/05/tinyweb-series-4-views-model-binding